# Why is laravel showing '["data"]' on webpage

Tags: php, database, laravel

Why when I use this form of retriving data from the database:

```
{{$homecontent->where('tabname', 'Maintenance')->pluck('tabname')}}
```

Laravel shows me the data with square brackets and quotes like this on my page:

```
["Maintenance"]
```

I just want it to give me back `Maintenance`

Comment: This does not make any sense at all... You could as well just write Mainenance as a string... ( You are querying for tabnames = Maintenance and then want to 'pluck' the tabname... ? )

Comment: I have different tabnames and information per tab that i want to display. I use the colum tabname and the actual tabname in this case "maintenance" so that i make sure i am picking and retrieving the right information for the right tabname. Alexey Mezenin give me what i was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pluck()` generates a collection (looks like an array here) and with `{{ }}` you're just printing it's content. That's why you see something like `["Content"]`

You could do something like this to print `Maintenance`:

```
{{ $homecontent->where('tabname', 'Maintenance')->first()->tabname }}
```

Or, if for some reason you need to use `pluck()`:

```
{{ $homecontent->where('tabname', 'Maintenance')->pluck('tabname')->toArray()[0] }}
```

Comment: Thank you very much that workt. Pluck isn't really a most i am pretty new to laravel so i am just using what i kind of know.